# AutoMapper - Map object properties to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, automapper

I am trying to map an object to a dictionary in a way that each property will be a dictionary item.

Object with `id` and `name` -> dictionary with two items containing property name and value.

I know it is a simple thing, but I was not able to find a solution for it. Maybe it is something I am not understanding...

I receive the following error:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Book -> Dictionary`2 (Destination member list)
Book -> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Keys
Values
Item
```

In the following code you can see my implementation:

```cs
using AutoMapper;

var book = new Book()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "A"
};

IMapper mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(
    config => config.CreateMap<Book, Dictionary<string, string>>()
        .ConstructUsing((source, dest) => new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "id", source.Id.ToString() },
            {"name", source.Name}
        })));

mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var bookData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

mapper.Map(book, bookData);

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: I read the documentation @LucianBargaoanu,  but the example does the opposite (from a dynamic to object).

Comment: I think you need to read it more carefully. Starting with the first sentence perhaps.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't so straightforward as you say. Mapping to Dictionary<string, string> throws an error, to Dictionary<string, object> it works.

Comment: It does what it says. You need to map it again to `Dictionary<string, string>`, but it seems easier to just use `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lucian mentioned in a comment, Automapper has built-in methods to convert object from/to `dynamic`, `Dictionary<string, object>`.

However, I think that there is an issue if you implement a converter to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Hence, it is better to build a custom implementation for the conversion as below:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary<T>(this T src) where T : new()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new ();
        
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
                
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
        {           
            result.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                       ? prop.GetValue(src)?.ToString()
                       : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prop.GetValue(src)));
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

For caller:

```cs
var bookData = book.ToDictionary();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PRDChb)

Comment: It's _a lot_ easier to use `Dicttionary<string, object>`. But if that's not possible, you can map that again to `Dicttionary<string, string>`. With AM or with `ToDictionary()`.